# How would I use .split() to split a string by \n instead of .split() reading \n as a new line

Tags: python, list, split

I'm trying to split up a string inside of a list into a list, and the string contains \n as a character.
Whenever I use .split("\n"), its of course splitting the string at a new line, but I need it to split at the character \n. Is there anyway to make .split() interpret it this way?

Example:

```
#original list
['\nSK Telecom Co. Ltd. ADR\nSKM\n12/31/2021\n1.49\nN/A\nN/A']
```

what id like to create with .split() function:

```
[ [SK Telecom CO. Ltd. ADR] , [SKM] , [12/31/2021] , [1.49], [N/A], [N/A] ]
```

if you have any idea on how to help i'd be very grateful, thanks!

Comment: Do you want the items to be lists? `.split('\n')` is not your problem, it gives the correct output, the items are just strings not lists.

Comment: "its of course splitting the string at a new line, but I need it to split at the character \n" - I'm not sure what you're trying to do since those are equivalent.

Comment: If what's actually in the string is a backslash followed by a 'n' (rather than an actual newline character), you'd write that in a string literal as `"\\n"` or `r"\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

what about:

```
a= ['\nSK Telecom Co. Ltd. ADR\nSKM\n12/31/2021\n1.49\nN/A\nN/A']
print(a[0].strip('\n').split('\n'))
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, I never new strip was a thing, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret your question literally, it looks like you want the result of split except that each string is contained in a list of length one.

Here's one approach.

```
orig = ['\nSK Telecom Co. Ltd. ADR\nSKM\n12/31/2021\n1.49\nN/A\nN/A']
result = [[s] for s in orig[0].split('\n')]
```

Or, if each entry of the list should be a list of characters,

```
orig = ['\nSK Telecom Co. Ltd. ADR\nSKM\n12/31/2021\n1.49\nN/A\nN/A']
result = [list(s) for s in orig[0].split('\n')]
```